# How to relink PowerBuilder 5.0 libraries?

Tags: powerbuilder

How can I relink PowerBuilder 5.0 libraries? When I open a PBL it only shows that same PBL. It has no descendants and cannot reference them which is why I also can't run the exe because of a reference error.

Comment: So you don't have any other .pbl files?  Only a single one?

Comment: My crystal ball is out being polished so I'll need more information from you. Is the error message when you run the EXE something you can post here? It could be an important clue. Now my favorite questions: Where did you get these files? When was the last time the program worked, and what's happened since then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rebuild your 'Library List'. I am pretty sure you can do it in the Application Painter (open the application object).

For PB 7 and earlier, the library list is located in the pb.ini file.